# Error: GRASS 7.0 and QGIS 2.8.1 in Linux Mint from the ubuntugis-unstable

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins

I have installed GRASS 7 and QGIS 2.8.1 from the https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable (Trusty 14.04) in Linux Mint 17.1 64bit(sudo apt-get install postgis libgdal1h grass-dev grass-gui monteverdi2) and QGIS doesn't recognize GRASS 7.0.0 Actually, I can see GRASS 7 on the QGIS toolbox but it doesn't work.

Is QGis prepared to support GRASS 7 through the QGIS/GRASS plugin?

When I run the GRASS 7 from QGIS toolbox I have the following Error:

```
GRASS_INFO_MESSAGE(14387,3): r.composite complete. Raster map created.
GRASS_INFO_END(14387,3)
GRASS_INFO_ERROR(14389,1): Raster map or group not found
GRASS_INFO_END(14389,1)
Execution of '/home/thayse/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' finished.
Cleaning up temporary files...

Starting GRASS GIS...
Executing '/home/thayse/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' ...
GRASS_INFO_ERROR(14401,1): Raster map or group not found
GRASS_INFO_END(14401,1)
Execution of '/home/thayse/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' finished.
Cleaning up temporary files...
Converting outputs

Loading resulting layers
```

Is it possible to have GRASS 6.4 installed in parallel to GRASS 7? What would be the best way to have both GRASS 6.4 and GRASS 7.0 installed on Linux Mint 17.1 from repositories?